# Заменить изображение CSS

Tags: css

Есть объект:

```
<div class="test">
  <img src="img.jpg">
</div>
```

Как при добавлении класса `active` к `test` заменить `src` у дочки родителя **через CSS**?

Чтобы на выходе получилось:

```
<div class="test active">
  <img src="new-img.jpg">
</div>
```

Это сниппет добавления класса

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  $('.test').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}

div {
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000493050021-abakgn-large.jpg">
</div>

<button>Добавить класс active</button>
```

Comment: Ищите про html-тег `<picture>` ... а через jQ... как вариант, `$('.active img').prop('src', 'ссылка');`

Comment: можно обойтись только css если слегка поменять верстку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  $('.test').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}

div {
  padding: 10px
}

.active img{
  content:url("http://imgur.com/SZ8Cm.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000493050021-abakgn-large.jpg">
</div>

<button>Добавить класс active</button>
```